# Filter on a master-detail view. yii2

Tags: gridview, frameworks, yii2

I want to display on a view, the details of an rawMaterial, and under it, a gridview of all the entries it has. In other words, a master-detail view.

My problem is that in the gridview of the Entries, which belongs to the current rawMaterial, when I try to filter an entry it doesn't work

Comment: show the code...  related controller Action and view

Comment: You have to take some time and think more clearly about your question, and help the people you are asking help you.  The people reading your question can't read your mind, so you have to tell us what tools you used, what code you wrote, some images and what the results of what you did was, what you expected, and most importantly, a description of exactly what "didn't work".  Read this before asking additional questions, and you will get a flood of people to help you.  http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ and http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: I have the following structure: - rawMaterial table. - rawMaterialentry table
Each rawMaterial -> has 1 or more entry.
This is the code i use for display the Entries of RawMaterial in the view of RawMaterial 
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [ 'nombre',
                ['class' => yii\grid\ActionColumn::className(),
                    'controller' => 'entradas-mat-prima', ],             
            ],
        ])?>